# Looping through non-empty rows with Python xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have an Excel worksheet with a column range, named `myRange`. The format of the sheet is so that the first 202 rows are formatted with borders. It is possible to have data pass row 208, or no data in the range.

I am trying to loop through elements of rows where `range_name = 'myRange'` is not empty/null. I have tried different approach, but they all seem to have flaws.

**Approach 1:** Loop using element in range

```
for element in sheet.range(range_name):
    print(element.value)
```

This prints `None` for all empty empty elements until row 202. It also does not allow me to access other elements of the row.

**Approach 2:** Find the number of rows containing data, and loop through the range

```
first_row_index = sheet.range(range_name).end('left').row
last_row_index = sheet.range(range_name).end('down').row
row_count = last_row_index - first_row_index

for i in range(0, row_count + 1):
    print(sheet.range(range_name)[i].value)
```

This works fine unless the range is empty. In that case, `last_row_index` returns 1048576.

**Approach 3:** Loop using range row length

```
for i in range(len(sheet.range(range_name).rows)):
    print(sheet.range(range_name)[i].value)
```

This prints `None` for all empty empty elements until row 202.

I assume Approach 3 with a `break` when the value is equal to `None` would be the best way to go? Any other suggestions?

Comment: One simple way of checking is using a if statement that check if the car is null you could do something like this

Answer (score 0):

What is your grand scheme you are trying to achieve? There are probably many ways to get there, so if we know why you are iterating through them it might help.

First, the formatting with borders has nothing to do with accessing the data. I'm also not sure why the named range goes to 202, but you can have data past that?

Approach 1 does not let you access anything beyond 202 because you are accessing the named range myRange. If you change the range of myRange in Excel you would then access whatever the new range is.

I'm beginning to think that you might believe you need to use a named range to access data? You can just do `rng = sht.range('A1:A500')` and then set the rng to the data `rng.value = 100` or whatever.

Personally I wouldn't iterate and would use pandas. If you might be working with other columns of data.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
# create new instance of Excel
app = xw.App()
# Get wb from only book open in that instance
wb = app.books[0]
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
rng = sht.range('A1:A20')
# Create dummy data in Excel, 1-7 in A1:A7, empty in A8:A10, 8-10 in A11:A13.
df = rng.options(pd.DataFrame, header=False, index=False).value
# Not sure what you want to do at this point. This will drop all NA's.
df = df.dropna()

>>> df
       0
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
6    7.0
10   8.0
11   9.0
12  10.0
```